# Changing the look of the a UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

Let's say I have the following .xib:
[My XIB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGFzs.png)

This .xib changes to a list of items in a JSON array, received from my remote JSON API when I run the app.

How do I make a "custom" cell view, that instead of a cell text, like the above, I will have an image on full screen width (like images displayed in Instagram app), and the text below it?

I've been trying to use cell.imageView.image but the image appears on the left side, small sized, without any option to customize it or make it bigger.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. To get an answer you should first show what you have tried. What you are looking for can be done simply by creating a custom `UITableViewCell` with your deisred layout. There are plenty of tutorials available for that, such as [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702) or [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) or [this](http://www.makemegeek.com/custom-uitableviewcell-example-ios/). A quick Google search would be helpful.

Comment: what you have to do is ,create a `custom tableveiw cell class` , select your cell , and go to your `identity inspector`, then select your created cell class from there and do your styles.

Comment: Thank you! Checking it out.